# Highlight/Color Text Within Cells from a List of Keywords

Tags: excel, vba

In Excel I have a list of keywords (or phrases) in a range of cells, and a range of cells that likely contain some or all of those keywords.

How can I automatically highlight or change the color of text matching any of those keywords *within* cells?  I do not want to highlight the entire cells, just change the color of matching keywords.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a VBA-Excel script that changes the color of matching text within cells using either a range of keywords/phrases to match or a keyword/phrase the user types when prompted.  The text colors can be picked from a color palette but red is the default.

The code is long, but here's the short version:

```
With cell.Characters(InStr(lastMatchPos, UCase(cell), UCase(keyword)), keywordLen).Font
    .Color = SelectedColor  ' color the keyword red
    .Bold = True    ' make the keyword bold
End With
```

"Cell" is the range of the cell being searched.

"LastMatchPos" is a variable that remembers where the last keyword match was found so that it can find additional matches further into that same cell.

`Characters` is used to change characters within the cell rather than to the entire cell.

`InStr` is the matching function.

`UCase` (Upper Case) is used on both the keyword and the cell being searched to make it case insensitive by comparing both the keyword and the text being searched in all caps.

Here's the full code.  Don't miss the two required functions below.

```
Public keywordLen As Integer, matchCount As Integer, lastMatchPos As Integer, j As Integer
Public SelectedColor As Long, i As Long, lastRow As Long
Public searchRange As Range
Public keywordType As String, keyword As String
Public keywordRange As Variant

Sub HighlightTextInCells()
' This script prompts the user to select cells with keywords,
'   and then select cells to search in for those keywords.
'
' Variables are declared as Public, above this sub, so that
'   they are available to pass from userforms to the main sub.
'
' FUNCTIONS CALLED:
'   PickNewColor()
'     Color2RGB()


'Open custom userform
    SelectKeywordRange.Show

'Get the last used row on the worksheet to set as a limit for
'  how far the script will search.
    lastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count + ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows(1).Row - 1

' Get user input.
    On Error Resume Next
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then Exit Sub

        If keywordType = "range" Then
            If InStr(keywordRange.Address, "$") Then
                If IsNumeric(Mid(keywordRange.Address, InStrRev(keywordRange.Address, "$") + 1)) Then
                    For k = 1 To Len(keywordRange.Address)
                        If Mid(keywordRange.Address, InStr(keywordRange.Address, ":") + k, 1) <> "$" And IsNumeric(Mid(keywordRange.Address, InStr(keywordRange.Address, ":") + k, 1)) Then
                            If Mid(keywordRange.Address, InStr(keywordRange.Address, ":") + k) > lastRow Then
                                Set keywordRange = Range(Left(keywordRange.Address, InStrRev(keywordRange.Address, "$") - 1) & lastRow)
                                Exit For
                            End If
                        End If
                    Next k
                Else
                    j = InStr(keywordRange.Address, ":")
                    Set keywordRange = Range(Left(keywordRange.Address, j - 1) & 1 & ":" & Mid(keywordRange.Address, j + 1) & lastRow)
                End If
            Else
                manualKeyword = keywordRange
            End If
        End If



        Set searchRange = Application.InputBox("Select the cells to search and highlight.", "SEARCH AREA", Type:=8) ' Prompt user to select cells to search and highlight.
            If Err.Number <> 0 Then Exit Sub

        If InStr(searchRange.Address, "$") Then
            If IsNumeric(Mid(searchRange.Address, InStrRev(searchRange.Address, "$") + 1)) Then
                For k = 1 To Len(searchRange.Address)
                    If Mid(searchRange.Address, InStr(searchRange.Address, ":") + k, 1) <> "$" And IsNumeric(Mid(searchRange.Address, InStr(searchRange.Address, ":") + k, 1)) Then
                        If Mid(searchRange.Address, InStr(searchRange.Address, ":") + k) > lastRow Then
                            Set searchRange = Range(Left(searchRange.Address, InStrRev(searchRange.Address, "$") - 1) & lastRow)
                            Exit For
                        End If
                    End If
                Next k
            Else
                j = InStr(searchRange.Address, ":")
                Set searchRange = Range(Left(searchRange.Address, j - 1) & 1 & ":" & Mid(searchRange.Address, j + 1) & lastRow)
            End If
        End If



        SelectedColor = PickNewColor(255)    ' Calls function "PickNewColor" with 255 (red) as the default
            If Err.Number <> 0 Then Exit Sub
    On Error GoTo 0

' Check each cell in the user defined range for any of the keywords, and highlight them.
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual   ' Stop calculating formulas during script
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False  ' Stop updating the screen during the script


    If keywordType = "range" Then
        For Each keyCell In keywordRange    ' Loop through every keyword
            keyword = keyCell.Value
            keywordLen = Len(keyword)   ' Get the length of the keyword for use later

            If keywordLen > 1 Then  ' Skip keywords that are blank or one character

            ' For each keyword, loop through each cell in the search range looking for that keyword
                For Each cell In searchRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
                    matchCount = CountChrInString(UCase(cell), UCase(keyword))
                    lastMatchPos = 1
                    ' Loop through a cell to find multiple instances of each keyword in that cell
                    For i = 1 To matchCount
                        If InStr(lastMatchPos, UCase(cell), UCase(keyword)) > 0 Then  ' Use "UCase" to compare the keywords and the text being searched all uppercase, effectively NOT case sensitive.
                            ' Set the text formatting for matched keywords
                            With cell.Characters(InStr(lastMatchPos, UCase(cell), UCase(keyword)), keywordLen).Font
                                .Color = SelectedColor  ' highlight the keyword red
                                .Bold = True    ' make the keyword bold
                            End With

                            lastMatchPos = InStr(lastMatchPos, UCase(cell), UCase(keyword)) + 1
                        End If
                    Next i
                Next cell
            End If
        Next keyCell

    Else
    'At this point, the keywordType <> "range", which means
    '  the user typed a single keyword instead of a range
    '  of keywords.
        keyword = keywordRange
        keywordLen = Len(keyword)   ' Get the length of the keyword for use later

        If keywordLen > 1 Then  ' Skip keywords that are blank or one character
        ' Loop through each cell in the search range looking for that keyword
            For Each cell In searchRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
                If Len(cell.Value) > 0 Then
                    matchCount = CountChrInString(UCase(cell), UCase(keyword))
                    lastMatchPos = 1
                    ' Loop through a cell to find multiple instances of each keyword in that cell
                    For i = 1 To matchCount
                        If InStr(lastMatchPos, UCase(cell), UCase(keyword)) > 0 Then  ' Use "UCase" to compare the keywords and the text being searched all uppercase, effectively NOT case sensitive.
                            ' Set the text formatting for matched keywords
                            With cell.Characters(InStr(lastMatchPos, UCase(cell), UCase(keyword)), keywordLen).Font
                                .Color = SelectedColor  ' highlight the keyword red
                                .Bold = True    ' make the keyword bold
                            End With

                            lastMatchPos = InStr(lastMatchPos, UCase(cell), UCase(keyword)) + 1
                        End If
                    Next i
                End If
            Next cell
        End If
    End If

    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic    ' Start calculating cell formulas again
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True   ' Start updating the screen again
End Sub
```

Here are two functions for the color picker, which are required to run the above script:

```
Function PickNewColor(Optional i_OldColor As Double = xlNone) As Double
'Picks new color
'  THIS FUNCTION USES THE "Color2RGB" FUNCTION
'
    Const BGColor As Long = 13160660  'background color of dialogue
    Const ColorIndexLast As Long = 32 'index of last custom color in palette

    Dim myOrgColor As Double          'original color of color index 32
    Dim myNewColor As Double          'color that was picked in the dialogue
    Dim myRGB_R As Integer            'RGB values of the color that will be
    Dim myRGB_G As Integer            'displayed in the dialogue as
    Dim myRGB_B As Integer            '"Current" color

      'save original palette color, because we don't really want to change it
      myOrgColor = ActiveWorkbook.Colors(ColorIndexLast)

      If i_OldColor = xlNone Then
        'get RGB values of background color, so the "Current" color looks empty
        Color2RGB BGColor, myRGB_R, myRGB_G, myRGB_B
      Else
        'get RGB values of i_OldColor
        Color2RGB i_OldColor, myRGB_R, myRGB_G, myRGB_B
      End If

      'call the color picker dialogue
      If Application.Dialogs(xlDialogEditColor).Show(ColorIndexLast, _
         myRGB_R, myRGB_G, myRGB_B) = True Then
        '"OK" was pressed, so Excel automatically changed the palette
        'read the new color from the palette
        PickNewColor = ActiveWorkbook.Colors(ColorIndexLast)
        'reset palette color to its original value
        ActiveWorkbook.Colors(ColorIndexLast) = myOrgColor
      Else
        '"Cancel" was pressed, palette wasn't changed
        'return old color (or xlNone if no color was passed to the function)
        PickNewColor = ""
        'PickNewColor = i_OldColor
      End If
End Function

'Converts a color to RGB values
'  THIS FUNCTION IS USED BY THE "PickNewColor" FUNCTION
Sub Color2RGB(ByVal i_Color As Long, o_R As Integer, o_G As Integer, o_B As Integer)
  o_R = i_Color Mod 256
  i_Color = i_Color \ 256
  o_G = i_Color Mod 256
  i_Color = i_Color \ 256
  o_B = i_Color Mod 256
End Sub
```